# Add data from one table to an array in another table based on matching value in postgres 15

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, one for reviews and another with urls for photos. I want to add the urls to an array in the reviews table. I want to match them based on the id for reviews they both have. Ideally I would be able to add the photos as a JSON object to the array, with one property for the photo id and another for the url. I'm new to postgres and SQL and struggling to come up with the query to be able to do this. Below is the sql for the two tables, below them is my attempt at a query:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.reviews
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    product_id integer NOT NULL,
    rating integer,
    date text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    summary text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    body text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    recommend boolean,
    reported boolean,
    reviewer_name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    reviewer_email text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    response text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    helpfulness integer,
    photos text[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT reviews_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.photos
(
    id integer,
    review_id integer,
    url text COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)


update reviews 
set photos = array_append(photos, photos.url)
where photos.review_id = reviews.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a FROM clause for the photos table:

```
update reviews 
  set photos = array_append(reviews.photos, photos.url)
from photos
where photos.review_id = reviews.id;
```

Prefixing the `photos` column on the right hand side of the assignment isn't strictly necessary, but if there is a table and a column with the same name, I find this to be more readable.

---

Note that `array_append(reviews.photos, photos.url)` can also be written as `reviews.photos || photos.url`

Comment: This appears like it may work! But the query is taking forever to run. It took over 16 minutes and I ended it (the number of rows is around 4 million). Is this normal or do I need to change the table structure to optimize lookup speed?